# ignore zero width non joiner in hunspell affix file

Tags: hunspell

I added this line to my affix file. But it has no effect on spell checker.

```
IGNORE <U-200C>
```

where  is the UTF-8 encoded U-200C ZWNJ

I found this suggestion here...

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60427

What is the correct way to ignore zero width non joiner in hunspell affix file?

Comment: Does your file contain `SET UTF-8` and is it actually a UTF-8 encoded file? Windows encoding defaults to UTF-16.

Comment: Yes. It is UTF-8 encoded file and SET UTF-8 is the first line.

Comment: IGNORE <200c> seems to work. I am not sure if removing U- is correct. Once someone confirms this, I can close this question.

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my research, the character after the IGNORE + space, is the encoded character in UTF-8. Not a representation of the character, but the character itself.

There may be other possible valid representations in the file.

Comment: I used "copy" button from https://unicode-explorer.com/c/200c and then pasted the character in affix file (linux O/S). That worked.